# Array initializer is valid at compile time but fails at run time when inside an object initializer

Tags: c#, .net, clr

While using an object initializer, I tried to instantiate an ICollection through an array initializer by mistake (I forgot the `new ...` part). What is quite strange, is that the compiler didn't complain at compile time, but rather I got an NullReferenceException at run time.

Here is some code to summarize the situation:

```
public class FakeClass
{
    public ICollection<string> StringsCollection { get; set; }

    public string[] StringsArray { get; set; }
}

FakeClass c = new FakeClass();
c.StringsCollection = { "test" }; // doesn't compile - ok
c.StringsCollection = new string[] { "test" }; // compiles - ok
c.StringsArray = { "test" }; // doesn't compile - ok
c.StringsArray = new string[] { "test" }; // compiles - ok

string[] strings = { "sdfqgrt" }; // compiles - ok
strings = { "sdfqgrt" }; // doesn't compile - ok

FakeClass c2 = new FakeClass
{
    StringsCollection = { "rthtj" }, // compiles and throws at run - why?
    StringsArray = { "egryjt" } // doesn't compile - ok
};
```

Of course I understand *why* this code cannot run, but I'm curious about how the compiler can accept such a thing.

Comment: You are using {get;set} which doesn't initialize the ICollection.  Add the initialization in the constructor for the class or replace { get; set;} with the call to the constructor : new ICollection<string>()

Comment: Initializers use nice syntax sugar, too much sugar does tend to produce rotten teeth.  Syntax is valid, you are using a *collection* initializer (not a field initializer), it only requires an Add() method.  So it calls the *getter* and not the setter to obtain the collection reference, it is null.  Avoiding mistakes like this is not so easy, you'll have to attend the School of Hard Knocks.

Answer (score 2):

```
StringsCollection = { "rthtj" }
```

There nothing wrong with this code. It calls implicit to `Add` method and add the string to the collection.

The NRE exception it because your property isn't initialised yet.

This will work

```
 public ICollection<string> StringsCollection { get; set; } = new List<string>();
```

**Update to answer on the comment**

For this code

```
FakeClass c = new FakeClass();
c.StringsCollection = new string[] { "test" }; 

FakeClass c2 = new FakeClass
{
    StringsCollection = { "dd" }
};
```

Look on the IL and pay attention to the different between the first and the second `StringCollection`

[image: IlSpy]

For the `setter` case you need expression like `new string[] {}` or new List() for the `getter` case you use the collection initializer.

Comment: Indeed, I saw somewhere that a `Add` method was called. But why is `c.StringsCollection = { "test" };` not even compiling then?